# Reference a pipeline job name in a YAML template

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to reference a job parameter's name in an Azure DevOps YAML template? I know that I could pass in the job name as its own string parameter, but I was hoping for something that's a little less clumsy.

template.yml

```yaml
parameters:
- name: MyJob
  type: job

jobs:
- ${{ parameters.MyJob }}

- job: Job2
  dependsOn: # How to make this depend on MyJob?
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  jobs:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      MyJob:
        job: SomeJobName
        steps:
        - script: echo Hello
```

I tried accessing `${{ parameters.MyJob.name }}` but it doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out, though it took a lot of trial and error to get the exact syntax and spacing right. The docs aren't super clear about spacing and expressions, and when to lead with a dash.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: MyJob
  type: job

jobs:
- ${{ parameters.MyJob }}

- job: Job2
  ${{ each pair in parameters.MyJob }}:
    ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'job') }}:
      dependsOn: ${{ pair.value }}
  steps:
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment, but as you see in previous answer, the property is not "name", but "job". You don't need the foreach then:

```
parameters:
- name: MyJob
  type: job

jobs:
- ${{ parameters.MyJob }}

- job: Job2
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.MyJob.job }}
  steps:
  ...
```

Comment: Why copy/paste the other answer ? You don't add any informations about the other one

Comment: See the "depends on", you'll spot the difference. Instead of going "foreach" on all parameters.MyJob properties, and writing result when the property name is "job", you could directly access parameters.MyJob.job property. Better readability, faster code.